# array join and create a url

Tags: jquery, arrays, sentence

I have a array of numbers like [ "1", "2", "3" ]

and i need to create a url like

https://api.edmunds.com/v1/api/configurator/withOptions?zip=90045&styleid=200701689&deselected=1&deselected=2&deselected=3&fmt=json&api_key=xxxxxxxxxx

and my array length will vary from empty to any no length, so depending on array length i need to create url

Array value assigned like in above url

```
 &deselected=1&deselected=2&deselected=3
```

Using jquery i tried map method it gives an array again,i need a url

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like

```js
var array = [ "1", "2", "3" ];
var params = array.length ? '&selected=' + array.join('&selected=') : '';
result.innerHTML =  params
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Using Array.map()

```js
var array = [ "1", "2", "3" ];
var params = array.map(function(value){
  return '&deselected='+value
}).join('');
result.innerHTML =  params
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: I assume they are using PHP or the like, so doesn't it need to be: &selected[]=?

Comment: Hey arun if you dont mind. Can you explain what this line mean

var params = array.length ? '&selected=' + array.join('&selected=') : '';

Comment: @divakar What's there to explain? It's a ternary operation.

Comment: @divakar if the array does not contain any elements then we want an empty string

Answer (score 0):

This should also work.

```
    var url = "https://api.edmunds.com/v1/api/configurator/withOptions?zip=90045&styleid=200701689", array = ["1", "2", "3"];

if (array.length) {
    var separator = "&deselected=";
    var queryParams = separator + array.join(separator);
    url = url + queryParams;
}
```